# Can a temporary change in carbohydrate intake change weight?

Tags: nutrition, diet

I've been on a low carb diet for months now, and I have noticed various weight differences from day to day when I wake up. However, the last couple of times I decided to eat a lot of carbs, I gained weight that persisted for a couple of days (about 3 lbs). I always weigh myself in the morning after using the restroom and eating a light breakfast.

Is there a known health phenomenon associated with carbs and changes in weight? Or is it more related to my body having been overweight before?

Answer (score 3):

Yes. You weight gain is only water weight though. Glycogen stores in the muscles require more water. This is the reason why your body holds on to water after eating carbs. It's perfectly normal. If you go back to your low carb diet the water will exit as you deplete your glycogen stores.

Comment: +1 For such a broad question this is a great answer!

Comment: Any references?

Comment: I learned about this topic while I was in school studying for my exercise physiology degree. I'm sure you can google glycogen water weight and find gobs of info on the topic.